# Building Bulma Navmenu in Wordpress - Why Isn't My Javascript Working To Toggle The Menu?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, bulma

I'm building a basic wordpress site using the underscores theme and the Bulma CSS framework.

I'm trying to include just the basic javascript code needed to toggle the navmenu open/closed on mobile, but it's not working (probably because I'm a total js noob).  Here's the site:

[sandbox.radionowhere.net](http://sandbox.radionowhere.net/)

As far as I can tell:

- the bulma.css is loading fine
- a very recent version of jquery is loading fine

I've just embedded the javascript in the body of the page for now for maximum simplicity; do I just have something wrong in the syntax somewhere, so the js and the html aren't making a connection?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't expect us to dig through your site to find the code of interest? Please do include the code that we need to see

Comment: Here is the js code in question: `<script>$(function() {

 $('.navbar-burger').click(function() {
     $('.navbar-menu, .navbar-burger').toggleClass('is-active');
    });
});
</script>`

Answer (score 1):

In your implementation, I encountered this issue.

```
$('.navbar-burger').click(function() {
 $('.navbar-menu, .navbar-burger').toggleClass('is-active');
});
```

this code snippet should be added inside your jquery onready function

```
$(function() {

 $('.navbar-burger').click(function() {
     $('.navbar-menu, .navbar-burger').toggleClass('is-active');
    });
});
```

Hope this helps. In the future add your code snippets when you are posting the question.

Comment: Thx, Praveen. I tried what I thought you were advising, but it didn't work, so I must not have understood. Do you mean that I should be including the following in the body of the page?         `<script>$(function() {

 $('.navbar-burger').click(function() {
     $('.navbar-menu, .navbar-burger').toggleClass('is-active');
    });
});
</script>`